# Angular routing with parameter not working

Tags: angular, url-routing, single-page-application

I've installed the new SPA templates for .NET Core, and created a new Angular project. Here is [a link](https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/04/20/dotnet-new-angular-single-page-application-setup-and-how-the-template-works/) if you're interested to give it a go. It comes with an example of routing. Now I am trying to get routing to work with a parameter, but I am having difficulty getting it to work.

In app.module.ts, I am defining the path as follows (with a parameter):

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
{ path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
{ path: 'fetch-data:id', component: FetchDataComponent },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
```

And this is how I am defining the router link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/fetch-data',3]">
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> Fetch data by ID
</a>
```

The path shows correct when I hover over the link, but when I click on it, it takes me back to home. I thought maybe it is conflicting with the path above it so I deleted the following line, but still it doesn't work:

```
{ path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

`{ path: 'fetch-data:id', component: FetchDataComponent },`

To

```
{ path: 'fetch-data/:id', component: FetchDataComponent },
```